# Error in non existing file

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I'm working on a .NET project, and I'm in a hard debugging period. I found a way to fix it, but when I read the error log in details, I realize that the error comes from a file that doesn't even exists !

```
dans C:\Users\Monstreur\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\HDPreDiag\ServiceWCF\Service1.svc.cs:ligne 56
```

I tried to search it or access it in command line, but as expected it says that the directory does not exists, how can it be possible ?

Comment: Do you use any libraries provided to you as DLLs from other people? I mean, not including NuGet packages. HDPreDiag can be an external library, and this path can be its debug information (if you have pdb).

Comment: Well the code has been written by someone else, I'm just continuing it

Comment: but the fact is, for this file in particular, I modified "mine", I added a function, so the error must be further than line 56

Answer (score 0):

You have modified the source code after the application was compiled.

The source references from any stack traces are based on the binaries, if the source code has been modified since the binary was produced, you will need to refer back to the original source code to make sense of any source code line references.

You should re-compile the program.  I would recommend also running using an interactive debugger through your development environment to improve your debugging experience.

Comment: How can I see that ?

Comment: That depends on how you are invoking it in the first place, maybe you can add some more detail to your question and I can then try to provide additional detail in my answer.

Comment: How I am invoking it ? What do you mean ?

Comment: How are you running the program which is generating the log / error message?

Comment: Well it's a .NET app so I launch it by clicking on the launch button, I don't know if that's what you want to know ?

Comment: Knowing that the app is someone else's, I'm continuing it on another computer, can it be a problem ?

Comment: yes as I mentioned in my answer you need to have the same source code which it was originally compiled from if you want those line numbers to make sense.

Comment: Wow okay I got it, I'll try it now